# How To Make A Column The Tooltip Content Google Sheets Graphs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm hoping to make a very simple plot of some banking information. I have the following table:

| Date | Total Savings | Transaction Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/27/2021 | 100 | work deposit |
| 05/29/2021 | 90 | lunch |

I want to plot the dates on the x-axis and total savings on the y-axis. This can be done very simply by pressing the built-in plotting button in Google Sheet while selecting Date and Total Savings.

The issue I'm writing on here to solved is that when I hover over a datapoint on this simple plot, I don't get the tooltip (or at least that's what I think it's called) I'm hoping for.

**I want this tool tip to include the Date and the Transaction Description. Right now, it includes the Date and the Total Savings (a screenshot of which I've attached below).**

[image: Google Sheet Current Behavior]

I know that the Transaction Description shouldn't appear the way I just described, but I don't know how to get the desired behavior (that being have Transaction Description replace Total Savings the way it is formatted in the screenshot).

I've been trying a bunch of things with macros but am really stumped. Any suggestions?

Edit:

Someone said it would be helpful if I added my code. I'm not completely sure what I'm doing but this is what I have:

```
function banking() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('A:C').activate();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asLineChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A1:C175'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Total vs. Date')
  .setXAxisTitle('Date')
  .setYAxisTitle('Total')
  .setPosition(16, 12, 69, 9)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

Comment: You might be able to get better answers, if you provide the code you tried or the code to create the chart.

Comment: @TheMaster I've added what I have so far.

Comment: Is your showing image your current situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide your expected situation as an image?